# Target "camera_models" links to target "CUDA::cublas" but the target was not found

Tags: cmake, makefile, cuda, ros2, nvidia-jetson

I am using ros2 foxy distribution on jetpuck 5.0.1 Ubuntu 20.04.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_executable):
  Target "Calibrations" links to target "CUDA::cusparse" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

Please help me to fix this issue, below I will provide my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(camera_models)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_compile_options(-Wextra -Wpedantic)

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED COMPONENTS cublas cudart cusolver cusparse)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem program_options system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Ceres REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CERES_INCLUDE_DIRS})


ament_export_include_directories(include)
ament_export_libraries(camera_models)
ament_export_dependencies(std_msgs)

# include_directories(
#     ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
#     )

include_directories("include")

add_executable(Calibrations 
    src/intrinsic_calib.cc
    src/chessboard/Chessboard.cc
    src/calib/CameraCalibration.cc
    src/camera_models/Camera.cc
    src/camera_models/CameraFactory.cc
    src/camera_models/CostFunctionFactory.cc
    src/camera_models/PinholeCamera.cc
    src/camera_models/PinholeFullCamera.cc
    src/camera_models/CataCamera.cc
    src/camera_models/EquidistantCamera.cc
    src/camera_models/ScaramuzzaCamera.cc
    src/sparse_graph/Transform.cc
    src/gpl/gpl.cc
    src/gpl/EigenQuaternionParameterization.cc)

# added from DEBUG
ament_target_dependencies(Calibrations rclcpp std_msgs OpenCV)

add_library(camera_models
    src/chessboard/Chessboard.cc
    src/calib/CameraCalibration.cc
    src/camera_models/Camera.cc
    src/camera_models/CameraFactory.cc
    src/camera_models/CostFunctionFactory.cc
    src/camera_models/PinholeCamera.cc
    src/camera_models/PinholeFullCamera.cc
    src/camera_models/CataCamera.cc
    src/camera_models/EquidistantCamera.cc
    src/camera_models/ScaramuzzaCamera.cc
    src/sparse_graph/Transform.cc
    src/gpl/gpl.cc
    src/gpl/EigenQuaternionParameterization.cc)

target_link_libraries(Calibrations ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${CERES_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(camera_models ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${CERES_LIBRARIES})
#target_link_libraries(Calibrations  ${CUDA_LIBSRARIES})
#target_link_libraries(camera_models  ${CUDA_LIBSRARIES})

# Install
install(TARGETS
    Calibrations
    DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
    )

install(TARGETS Calibrations camera_models
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

install(TARGETS Calibrations
    RUNTIME DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
  
install(DIRECTORY include/
    DESTINATION include/
)
  
ament_package()
```

I have tried these two lines

```
#target_link_libraries(Calibrations  ${CUDA_LIBSRARIES})
#target_link_libraries(camera_models  ${CUDA_LIBSRARIES})
```

but didn't have any success, so I hope that someone can help me).

Comment: `find_package(CUDA)` is deprecated. Use [`find_package(CUDAToolkit)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html) instead if you have at least CMake 3.17.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer)